# calculating string length causes confustion

Tags: lua

I am confused by the following output:

```
local a = "string"
print(a.len)        -- function: 0xc8a8f0
print(a.len(a))     -- 6
print(len(a)) 
--[[
/home/pi/test/wxlua/wxLua/ZeroBraneStudio/bin/linux/armhf/lua: /home/pi/Desktop/untitled.lua:4: attempt to call global 'len' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /home/pi/Desktop/untitled.lua:4: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
]]
```

What is the proper way to calculate a string length in Lua?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The proper way is `#a`

Comment: Thank you, but why `print(a.len(a))` works?

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
a = "string"
string.len(a)
```

Or:

```
a = "string"
a:len()
```

Or:

```
a = "string"
#a
```

EDIT: your original code is not idiomatic but is also working

```
> a = "string"
> a.len
function: 0000000065ba16e0
> a.len(a)
6
```

The string `a` is linked to a table (named metatable) containing all the methods, including `len`.

A method is just a function, taking the string as the first parameter.

`function a.len (string) .... end`

You can call this function, `a.len("test")` just like a normal function. `Lua` has a special syntax to make it easier to write. You can use this special syntax and write `a:len()`, it will be equivalent to `a.len(a)`.

Comment: Thank you, but why `print(a.len(a))` works?

Answer (score 3):

> print(a.len)        -- function: 0xc8a8f0

This prints a string representation of `a.len` which is a function value. All strings share a common metatable.

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 6.4 String Manipulation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4):

> The string library provides all its functions inside the table string.
> It also sets a metatable for strings where the __index field points to
> the string table. Therefore, you can use the string functions in
> object-oriented style. For instance, string.byte(s,i) can be written
> as s:byte(i).

So given that `a` is a string value, `a.len` actually refers to `string.len`

For the same reason

> print(a.len(a))

is equivalent to `print(string.len(a))` or `print(a:len())`. This time you called the function with argument `a` instead of printing its string representation so you print its return value which is the length of string `a`.

> `print(len(a))`

on the other hand causes an error because you attempt to call a global nil value. `len` does not exist in your script. It has never been defined and is hence `nil`. Calling nil values doesn't make sense so Lua raises an error.

According to [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.4.7 Length Operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7)

> The length of a string is its number of bytes. (That is the usual
> meaning of string length when each character is one byte.)

You can also call `print(#a)` to print `a`'s length.

The length operator was introduced in Lua 5.1,